# Unable to occupy hidden view space in swift

Tags: swift, swift4.2

I have 3 view View A , View B and Table view where View A is optional.
i.e. Only authenticated person can interact with View A.

So i have hided the View A for unauthenticated user by

```
viewA.isHidden = true
```

But this view is still taking space. What i want is if View A is hidden, Allow View B and table view take view A Space.

[image]

what I want is show in below pic.

[image]

Comment: So I suppose you are using UIStackView? Do you have any height constraints? Maybe you should post more code on what you have done

Comment: if you are not using stack view. you need to set width constraints 0 of viewA with is isHidden = true other wise set width constraint. But stack view is preferable in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have to add two constraint

1. vertical space from view B to View A with constant = 10 and priority = 999 (high)
2. top space from view B to safe area with constant = 10 and priority = 750 (low)

the constraint which has higher priority is considered first. Add outlet connection to the ViewController.

when you want to hide view A then change the priority of second constraint to 999(high) and first constraint to 750(low) programatically.

```
constaraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 750)
```